# Gmail script only pull from first email of each thread. Need return data from each message

Tags: multithreading, google-apps-script

I'm trying to parse extract data from g-mail messages using a script that uses regex. Got the rest of the main functions of the script working however there is one pretty big issue.

The script is only returning data from the first message of each thread. I would like it to return the data from each message in each thread, Ive been playing around with it but so far no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
//var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  // Have to get data separate to avoid google app script limit!
  var start = 0;
  var threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread AND label:desc",0,100); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();
    messages[0].markRead();

    // implement your own parsing rule inside
    if (content) {
      var tmp;
      tmp = content.match(/\b([A-B\d][A-B\d]{4})\b/);
      var cod = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Error';

      tmp = content.match(/\b(\d+[R])/);
      var prom = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Error';

      tmp = content.match(/\b(\d{2}\.\d{2}\)\b/);
      var exp = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Error';

      sheet.appendRow([cod, prom, exp]);

      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand the logic of your current script you need to re-learn it. For example, what do you think this snippet of your code does? `for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();` Have you read the official documentation to deduce the types and classes associated with the variables you're using?

Comment: Thanks for response @tehhowch  Sorry, I am very amateur in this. This script only edited for me but the first code not create for me. I read the official documentation and change some many times the code but no luck to work properly.  This is other code I have tried but no luck:  https://www.codepile.net/pile/D2OG702E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads), the resource `Users.threads` has the next structure:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "snippet": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long,
  "messages": [
    users.messages Resource
  ]
}
```

> Notice the "messages" property, how it contains a
>   [list](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) (or array) of
>   `users.messages`.

---

In your code:

```
 var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
```

You store each one of these lists in the `messages` variable every time the loop completes a cycle. That's what `i` is for, to represent each position of the `users.messages` array. You can read more about loops [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

---

The issue with your code is that you should do the same loop you did with `threads`, but with `messages`, as in Gmail, each single `thread` can have multiple `messages`, as I said in the yellow box above :).

```
 var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();
 messages[0].markRead();
```

The reason you are only getting the first message of each thread is you are only accessing the `0` index position (which in an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), it's the first position) of messages.

---

In consequence, you need another `for` loop to iterate over all the messages of each thread:

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){ //You can't repeat i, so we use j, for example
        var content = messages[j].getPlainBody();
        messages[j].markRead();

        // implement your own parsing rule inside
        if (content) {
        ... etc
```

Also, remember to add another `}` to close the loop *after* `Utilities.sleep`

Hope this helps! Don't hesitate to ask any other doubt.

Comment: Awesome @Jescanellas ! Many Many Thanks!  Perfect explanation and now working perfect!  I am very new with javascript and google apps script. I have read the documentation but could not understand some things.

Comment: You are welcome! I recommend you to look at the different [Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/apps-script) for Apps Script, as they are ready to run and provide great examples to learn.